# Hive: Convert String to Integer

Tags: string, hive, user-defined-functions, hiveql

I am looking for a Built-in UDF to convert values of a string column to integer in my hive table for sorting using SELECT and ORDER BY. I searched in the Language Manual, but no use. Any other suggestions also welcome.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

`cast(str_column as int)`

From: [Language manual UDFs - type conversion functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-TypeConversionFunctions)

Comment: Just curious, but will this return a unique int for every possible string, including non-ascii ones (e.g.: foreign words or phrases)?

Comment: @wardw123 it will return `NULL` if string is non-numeric or too large/small to fit `int` data type

Answer (score 7):

If the value is between –2147483648 and 2147483647, cast(string_filed as int) will work. else cast(string_filed as bigint) will work

```
    hive> select cast('2147483647' as int);
    OK
    2147483647
    
    hive> select cast('2147483648' as int);
    OK
    NULL
    
    hive> select cast('2147483648' as bigint);
    OK
    2147483648
```

Answer (score -2):

It would return NULL but if taken as BIGINT would show the number

Comment: Could you explain your answer please?