# Invalid function To_Number in Hive

Tags: sql, function, hive, teradata, coalesce

i ran the following query on teradata it was successful but when running on hive it got an error

```
Coalesce(CASE WHEN To_Number(STG_156_110_CUID.ID_ISSUE_DATE)  >= '29991231' OR 
To_Number(STG_156_110_CUID.ID_ISSUE_DATE)  <= '1901000' OR 
To_Number(STG_156_110_CUID.ID_ISSUE_DATE) IS NULL THEN Cast(NULL AS DATE Format 'YYYYMMDD') 
ELSE Cast(STG_156_110_CUID.ID_ISSUE_DATE AS DATE Format 'YYYYMMDD')
END, Cast ('19000101' AS DATE Format 'YYYYMMDD' )) AS ID_ISSUE_DATE
```

Error

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10011]: Invalid function 
To_Number
```

what should i replace to_number with?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hive: Convert String to Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12358166/13927534)

Comment: Or if the field's a date: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50259888/361842

Comment: there is no built-in To_Number function. Instead, you can use the cast function to convert a string to a numeric type.

So in your case, you can replace the To_Number function with cast(STG_156_110_CUID.ID_ISSUE_DATE as int). This will cast the ID_ISSUE_DATE column to an integer type, which you can then compare to other integer values.

Here's the updated query:

Comment: coalesce(case when cast(STG_156_110_CUID.ID_ISSUE_DATE as int) >= 29991231 or 
                cast(STG_156_110_CUID.ID_ISSUE_DATE as int) <= 1901000 or 
                STG_156_110_CUID.ID_ISSUE_DATE is null 
           then cast(null as date format 'YYYYMMDD') 
           else cast(STG_156_110_CUID.ID_ISSUE_DATE as date format 'YYYYMMDD')
      end, 
      cast('19000101' as date format 'YYYYMMDD')) as ID_ISSUE_DATE

Comment: Please note that this assumes that the ID_ISSUE_DATE column is stored as a string in the format 'YYYYMMDD'. If it is stored in a different format, you may need to adjust the cast accordingly.

Comment: Just FYI - It is bad practice to convert one value to number and then compare with a string. Teradata will accept it (for historical reasons) and implicitly convert *both* values to FLOAT to do the comparison. Some other databases will just throw an error.